# BizTalk 2010: DateTime Issue

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

BizTalk Server 2010 has the following system configuration

```
Server: Windows Server 2008
FrameWork: .Net 4.0
```

Through HTTP when BizTalk receives the DateTime combination, it is being converted as follows.

```
DateTime Sent: **2010-06-01T00:00:00-04:00**
DateTime Received and logged: **2010-06-01T00:00:00-04:00** (BizTalk 2010)
```

In the BizTalk 2004 (our old integration environment, using .Net Framework 1.1), BizTalk is receiving and logging the message in the following formats.

```
DateTime Sent: 2010-06-01T00:00:00-04:00
DateTime Received and Logged: 2010-06-01T00:00:00.0000000-04:00
```

As it can be seen that leading zeros are being added to the DateTime. Following are some more combinations that are being a mystery to me.

```
Datetime Sent to BizTalk 2004: 2011-03-01T00:00:00-05:00
DateTime received and Logged: 2010-06-01T00:00:00.0000000-04:00
```

The schemas are defined in both the environments as xsd:dateTime. I'm unable to find an explanation to the fact that why BizTalk or the framework is behaving differently in both the environments.

Note: No Date Transformation occurs in any of the environment.

In BizTalk 2010, I can see that the TimeZone (-4:00) is missing.

Would like to know if there are any settings that we need to do fix for this DateTime issue.

Comment: They aren't "leading zeros", it is just the date time including milliseconds (after the period) in the BizTalk 2004 vesion. Do you need accuracy to the millisecond?  You say that TimeZone (-4:00) is missing, however in all the examples show above including the BizTalk 2010 you can clearly see the -4:00 at the end of the date time.  What is doing the logging?  If it is custom code can you please show the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the timezone on the server (or servers in the group). BizTalk Host Instances use the time zone and regional settings from the machine.

Don't set the time zone programmaticly from your application code, since processes and threads can be shared across multiple instances and you will run into very nasty problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check what are the Timezone settings of the servers in the registry 
You can find the key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation

However, pelase make sure you take a backup of your registry before making any changes.